# How can I get information about any object clicked by the mouse cursor ?

Tags: winapi

Programmatically on Windows, How can I get information about any object clicked by the mouse cursor, ex: type (textbox, file, folder, icon), property (name, innertext).

I have used SetWindowsHookEx in order to get mouse click information like (X,Y) and (RightClick, LeftClick), but I'm trying now to know what is under this click, however the programming language was?

Comment: Use the automation framework.

Answer (score 2):

The most general (and therefore mostly useless) information is just the X,Y coordinates. From there you need to be more specific to know what kind of information you want to get. If you want window information, there is [`WindowFromPoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).